# Express site giving 503

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My express site's giving 503 error. I've searched almost for an hour everywhere now, but nothing helps. Heres the **FULL CODE** below, any help would be appreciated loads.
PS: Im trying to make a comment system. I used mongoose, express and axios for posting with a few minor npm modules.
code: **{SOLVED}**

Comment: What route causes the 503 error.  You should include in your question, the code for the exact route (pasted into the question, not as an external link) that causes the error and any code for middleware that might also be involved in that route.  We would also like to know what debugging have you done?  How far in the route handler does the code get before it bails with the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, this:

```
app.use(express.json);
```

is wrong and should be:

```
app.use(express.json());
```